# Hibernate 6: Json type with Local Date var

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I recently switched to spring 3.0 and hibernate now supports json type definition like this:

```
        @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
        var request: ReportRequestDto,
```

but the problem is that `ReportRequestDto` has `val from: LocalDate`, this causes an exception when saving entity:

```
Java 8 date/time type `java.time.LocalDate` not supported by default
```

I have the `jackson-datatype-jsr310` dependency in my pom, also I have a configuration for object mapper:

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
        val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
        objectMapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
        objectMapper.registerKotlinModule()
        objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
        return objectMapper
    }
```

It looks like hibernate is not "autowiring" the object mapper, thus it doesn't have the java time module registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create `HibernatePropertiesCustomizer` bean as mentioned [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33870)

Below is the sample Kotlin code snippet:

```
@Bean
    fun jsonFormatMapperCustomizer(objectMapper: ObjectMapper): HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {
        return HibernatePropertiesCustomizer { properties: MutableMap<String, Any> ->
            properties[AvailableSettings.JSON_FORMAT_MAPPER] = JacksonJsonFormatMapper(objectMapper)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be nice to try injecting an object mapper as bean. Can you please create a JIRA for that? In the meantime, you can register a custom format mapper with a custom Jackson `ObjectMapper` by registering a property `org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings#JSON_FORMAT_MAPPER`/`hibernate.type.json_format_mapper` to `new org.hibernate.type.format.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatMapper(yourObjectMapper)`.